# AdMob and libGdx issue

Tags: android

im working up by this tutorial it look really simple [tutorial](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_dummy_interface.php)
im using eclipse

i added the google lib - added the mainfest - changed the android launcher

my main game class job is only to set the screen to a different class so i`//`the code and set a green background to test.

but my android launcher show me the"old version" of the game and not the new one with the changes i did clean,refresh and it does not help also closed and reopen

my desktop launcher working just fine and showing the green screen and no ads

but i really want to see if i made it work and ads are display in the android project

am i doing some thing wrong?

my android launcher:

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
 import com.mygdx.game.AdsController;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {

private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-9296014109421237/4852192701";//funky code

AdView bannerAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Create a gameView and a bannerAd AdView
    View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
    setupAds();

    // Define the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(bannerAd, params);

    setContentView(layout);
}

public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000); // black
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
}

@Override 
public void showBannerAd() {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                AdRequest ad = builder.build();
                bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void hideBannerAd() {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

}
}
```

my main game class:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends Game {




private AdsController adsController;

public MyGdxGame(AdsController adsController){
       if (adsController != null) {
           this.adsController = adsController;
       } else {
           this.adsController = new DummyAdsController();
       }
}

@Override
public void create () {
    //this.setScreen(new MaimMenuClass(this));
    adsController.showBannerAd();
}
@Override
public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}


  }
```

my mainafest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygdx.game.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and the two interfaces:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

public interface AdsController {
public void showBannerAd();
public void hideBannerAd();
}


package com.mygdx.game;

public class DummyAdsController implements AdsController {

@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
}

@Override
public void hideBannerAd() {
}
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

May you try this in your game class :

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

private AdsController adsController;

public MyGdxGame(AdsController adsController){
       if (adsController != null) {
           this.adsController = adsController;
       } else {
           this.adsController = new DummyAdsController();
       }
}

@Override
public void create () {
    setScreen(new MainMenuClass(this, adsController));
    //adsController.showBannerAd();
}

public void render() {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

In your MainMenuClass, call your banner with

```
adsController.showBannerAd();
```

Hope it helps.